# Identifying holomorphic sections of a line bundle with homogeneous functionals

Tags: complex-analysis

I was told that given a holomorphic line bundle $L \to X$ we can identify the space of sections $\Gamma(X,L^k)$ with the space of $k$-homogeneous holomorphic functions on $L^*$ -- let's call the latter e.g. $\mathcal{O}(L^*)_{(k)}$.

I'm not sure how this isomorphism is supposed to work -- does anyone happen to know some pointers to literature where this is discussed?

Thanks!